# 1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders using Laravel 5.6

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

**Getting following error**

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders

**My query has become due to data in the table recently**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE col1 = 'some-val'
  AND col2 NOT IN ('va1', 'val2', 80k values... )
```

*I am using Laravel 5.6*

```
$data_will_be_skipped = OtherModel::select('code')
        ->where('col1', 0)
        ->orWhere('col2', 1)
        ->groupBy('col3')
        ->pluck('col3')->toArray();
```

$data_will_be_skipped is now approx **80k** arrays

```
Model::where('col1', 'some-val')->whereNotIn('col2', $data_will_be_skipped)->get();
```

Comment: Where are you getting the values for `not in` array ? if they are from some tables in the DB only. consider using joins instead of `not in`. Whether using laravel or not, `not in` itself has packet size limits

Comment: Your current approach is not efficient from indexing perspectives as well

Comment: yes not-in values are being get by some other table in the db.

Comment: Please update your question to add more details about which tables are you getting them from. What is the relationship between the two tables ? What is the logic behind getting these values from the other table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has a limit of 65,535 parameters in prepared statements.

Use a subquery instead:

```php
$data_will_be_skipped = OtherModel::select('col3')
    ->where('col1', 0)
    ->orWhere('col2', 1);
Model::where('col1', 'some-val')
    ->whereNotIn('col2', $data_will_be_skipped)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Awesome :-) you are champ!

Comment: sure, I was just accepting and I had to attend the meeting.

Comment: I am still getting error: 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders (SQL: select `callDate`, `uniqueid` from `cdr` where `uniqueid` not in (1594624402.0, 1594624402.4, 1594624425.18, 1594624425.22, 1594624425.32, 1594624448.52, 1594624578.78, 1594624578.82, 1594624620.111, 1594624620.115, 1594624620.119, 1594627078.156..........................

Comment: @JaberAlNahian - I'm having the same problem. Did you get a solution?

Comment: @Tom I forgot, maybe I had to increase limit

Answer (score 0):

No matter how many items u have in array to check in wherein

the simple way to do it

```
$data = model::whereRaw("id not in (".implode(',',$data_will_be_skipped).")")->get();
```